# Mysql CREATE FUNCTION syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION GET_DISTANCE (LatBegin float,LngBegin float,LatEnd float,LngEnd float)
    RETURNS float
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Distance FLOAT
    DECLARE EARTH_RADIUS FLOAT
    SET EARTH_RADIUS =  6378137.00

    DECLARE dlat FLOAT
            DECLARE dlng FLOAT
    SET LatBegin =  LatBegin * PI()/ 180.0
    SET LngBegin = LngBegin * PI() / 180.0
        SET LatEnd = LatEnd * PI() / 180.0
    SET LngEnd = LngEnd * PI() / 180.0

    SET dlat =  LatBegin - LatEnd
    SET dlng = LngBegin - LngEnd

    SET Distance = (1-cos(dlat))/2.0+cos(LatBegin)*cos(LatEnd)*((1-cos(dlng))/2.0)
    SET Distance = asin(sqrt(Distance)) * EARTH_RADIUS *2.0
    SET Distance = Round(Distance * 10000,2) / 10000
    RETURN Distance
    END
```

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_dlat FLOAT;
            DECLARE dlng FLOAT;
        SET LatBegin =  LatBegin * PI(' at line 8

Answer (score 2):

You've written the whole function as one big statement. You need to use delimiters. Here's the example from [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html):

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> CALL simpleproc(@a);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must end each line/command with a `;` so

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE Distance FLOAT;
    DECLARE EARTH_RADIUS FLOAT;
    SET EARTH_RADIUS =  6378137.00;
```

etc .....

Answer (score 0):

Add ';' as ManseUK suggested.

All declarations must be at the begining of the BEGIN...END clause -

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION GET_DISTANCE(LatBegin FLOAT,
                                                    LngBegin FLOAT,
                                                    LatEnd   FLOAT,
                                                    LngEnd   FLOAT
                                                    )
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
  DECLARE Distance     FLOAT;
  DECLARE EARTH_RADIUS FLOAT;
  DECLARE dlat         FLOAT;
  DECLARE dlng         FLOAT;

  SET EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137.00;
  SET LatBegin = LatBegin * PI() / 180.0;
  SET LngBegin = LngBegin * PI() / 180.0;
  SET LatEnd = LatEnd * PI() / 180.0;
  SET LngEnd = LngEnd * PI() / 180.0;
  SET dlat = LatBegin - LatEnd;
  SET dlng = LngBegin - LngEnd;

  SET Distance = (1 - COS(dlat)) / 2.0 + COS(LatBegin) * COS(LatEnd) * ((1 - COS(dlng)) / 2.0);
  SET Distance = ASIN(SQRT(Distance)) * EARTH_RADIUS * 2.0;
  SET Distance = ROUND(Distance * 10000, 2) / 10000;
  RETURN Distance;
END
```